# Как сделать юникодную строку читабельной?

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x

Что делать если при чтении списка - символы читабельны, а после его конвертации в строку - теряют читабельность? Что делать со строкой? Научите.

Например:

```
for i in range(0, len(fullTEXT)):
    print fullTEXT[i].text
    textList.append(fullTEXT[i].text)
```

`Известно, что нервные клетки`

```
fullTEXT = str(textList)
print fullTEXT
```

`[u'\u0418\u0437\u0432\u0435\u0441\u0442\u043d\u043e, \u0447\u0442\u043e \u043d\u0435\u0440\u0432\u043d\u044b\u0435 \u043a\u043b\u0435\u0442\u043a\u0438']`

Comment: Переходить на третий питон, там такой проблемы нет)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, буду знать. А решения для 2.х нету?

Comment: Обидно, всё встало из-за этого. Я так понимаю ошибка `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)` тоже из-за этого.

Comment: А что встало-то, для чего это нужно? А вторая ошибка - следствие неполного понимания работы строк, наверно

Comment: @andreymal: Питон 3, где `repr()` может показывать некоторые Юникодные символы без `'\uhhhh'` эскейпов, только делает проблему менее очевидной. В Питоне 3 я наблюдал, как люди начинали в подобных ситуациях жаловаться: "а почему у меня в тексте `['',]` символы появились" (или хуже: в коде начали бы появляться `.replace('[', '')` итд). Настоящая проблема не связана с версией Питона, а с отсутствием понимания разницы между `obj` и `repr(obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

Если Ваша цель - получить одну строку из списка строк, хранящихся в списке, можно сделать, что-то вроде:

```
>>>fullTEXT = [u'Известно, что нервные клетки', u'не восстанавливаются']
>>>print ' '.join(fullTEXT)
Известно, что нервные клетки не восстанавливаются
```

Если же цель другая, опишите чего хотите добиться, выполняя:

```
fullTEXT = str(textList)
print fullTEXT
```

Совет. Ваш цикл:

```
for i in range(0, len(fullTEXT)):
    print fullTEXT[i].text
    textList.append(fullTEXT[i].text)
```

можно упростить убрав len и range:

```
for item in fullText:
    print item.text
    textList.append(item.text)
```

Comment: A еще круче будет `textList += [item.text for item in fullText]`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно примерно так:

```
>>> mylist = [u"Известно, что нервные клетки", u"Что-то совсем другое"]
>>> print u'[%s]' % ', '.join(['"%s"' % item for item in mylist])
["Известно, что нервные клетки", "Что-то совсем другое"]
```