# Обработка кириллической строки полученной через pymssql

Tags: python, windows, кодировка, sql-server, python-3.x

Начал работать с Python, и вот какую проблему получил используя pymssql на Windows:

Получаем запросом строку с кириллицей, делаем fetch этой строки. Если пытаемся эту строку напечатать в консоль или сохранить в файл, то получаем:

```
File "C:\py\lib\encodings\cp866.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: character maps to <undefined>
```

Если попытаться применить к строке метод `.encode('utf8')`, то на выдаче получаем без ошибки, но в непонятном виде:

```
b'\xc3\x87\xc3\xa0\xc3\xa2\xc3\xae\xc3\xa4\xc3\xb1\xc3\xaa\xc3\xa0\xc3\xbf'
```

Пробовал в настройки соединения с MSSQL сервер ставить charset параметр utf-8 - не помогло.

При этом все отлично работает на Linux, все выводится без всяких проблем. Использую Python 3.4.

Comment: вот [это](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/431817/178576) не про то же?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка связана с тем, что в виндовой консоли никакой не юникод, а, как видно из текста ошибки, кодировка cp866, а в ней, очевидно, присутствуют не все символы из юникода. А именно — в приведённой строке написано «Çàâîäñêàÿ» (а вовсе не «Заводская», как может ошибочно считать автор вопроса), и ни одного из этих символов в кодировке cp866 не имеется :)

Увы, грамотного решения данной проблемы я не знаю и могу посоветовать лишь костыль (может, кто-нибудь что-нибудь посоветует получше):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.buffer.write('Çàâîäñêàÿ'.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) + b'\n')
```

Однако перед этим нужно перепроверить все параметры подключения к базе данных и содержимое самой базы, чтобы получать оттуда всё-таки «Заводская», а не «Çàâîäñêàÿ»: косяк ещё где-то там. Как вариант — в параметрах подключения почему-то latin-1 (стоит по умолчанию в библиотеке?), а данные самой базы при этом хранятся в cp1251.

Comment: Решил на windows использовать pyodbc - с ним проблема ушла, да и код написанный не надо препарировать, за исключением нескольких строк для подключения. А так вы скорее всего правы насчет параметров подключения, у библиотеки pymssql есть возможность передать в подключении параметр charset, но когда я пытался туда подставлять значения cp1251, windows-1251 и прочие варианты, то python прекращал свою работу даже не выбрасывая в консоль ошибок, а просто с обычным windows-окном ошибки.

Comment: Попробуйте достать из базы строки, содержащие, например, символы ©, «, », ± или –. Они есть в cp1251, но их нет в cp866, и при их появлении проблема должна вновь проявиться.

Answer (score 0):

Так у меня работает! Установив в соединении charset=cp1251:

```
create_engine(
    "mssql+pymssql://"
         +config['COMMON']['userdb']
         +":"+config['COMMON']['passdb']
         +"@"+config['COMMON']['namedb']
         +"/?database="+config['COMMON']['database']
         +"?charset=cp1251",
    isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED",
    deprecate_large_types=True,
    echo=False,
)
```

Comment: Для сборки строки из кусков удобнее форматирование через format или f-строки использовать. Например, так (по именам из фигурных скобок будут вытаскиваться значения из словаря `config['COMMON']`): `"mssql+pymssql://{userdb}:{passdb}@{namedb}/?database={database}?charset=cp1251".format(**config['COMMON'])`

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/766425)

Comment: @cheops вообще-то это решение вопроса.

Comment: @insolor Согласен, буду внимательнее.