# Как в python 2.7.13 пользователь может вводить русские буквы в raw_input()?

Tags: кодировка, python-2.7

Пример кода.

```
# -*-coding: utf-8-*-
print u"Введите что-нибудь умное"
var_anybody = raw_input()
print u"Вот что он написал %r" %r
```

Если пользователь введет русские буквы, получается что-то вроде этого:

```
\xaf\xe0\xa8\xa2\xa5\xe2
```

1. Подскажите как сделать, что бы пользователь мог вводить русские буквы и русские буквы корректно отображались.
2. А так же помогите пожалуйста как сделать подсказки на русском в raw_input('нажмите кнопку')

Comment: Я придумал как задавать подсказку легкой хитростью:
`print u"Ответьте на вопрос", raw_input() `
но опять же она не работает  если raw_input() назначить в переменную
`print u"Ответьте на вопрос",  var_2 = raw_input()`
В этом случае выдаст ошибку. Есть мысли как с этим бороться?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431817/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8E%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: @titov_andrei Спасибо данная тема помогла найти мне ответы на мои вопросы. Моя тема может быть актуально, потому что тот вопрос на все возможные запросы от raw_input() в гугле не находится.

Answer (score 1):

У вас буквы уже нормально вводятся. Проблема в том как вы их пытаетесь отображать. `"%r" % s` вызывает `repr(s)`, которое вернёт текстовое представление объекта полезное для отладки.

В вашем случае, вы видите текстовое представление байтовой строки (все байты из не-ascii диапазона экранированы используя `\xHH`).

Чтобы напечатать, что `raw_input()` вернула, печатайте переменную напрямую:

```
s = raw_input(prompt)
print u'Получил', s
```

Если `isinstance(prompt, unicode)` и `raw_input(prompt)` не работает у вас (к примеру, UnicodeEncodeError выбрасывается), то используйте:

```
print prompt,
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Это достаточно, чтобы произвольные Unicode символы поддерживать, для ввода/вывода на системах с utf-8 locale (не Windows). На Windows, чтобы ввод/вывод работал даже для символов вне ANSI/OEM code pages в консоли (чтобы ввод на нескольких языках поддерживать, а не только язык Windows), можно использовать `win-unicode-console` пакет. См. ещё [Проблемы с кодировкой Python 2.7](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/229015/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Узнал ответ на свой основной вопрос.

Можно решить следующим образом:

```
# -*-coding: utf-8-*-
print u"Введите что-нибудь умное"
var_anybody = raw_input()
print u"Вот что он написал ", "".join(var_anybody)
```

Теперь если пользователь введет русские слова они выведутся на экран правильно.

2. Вопрос с комментария. Что бы вывести в одну строку:

   print u"Ответьте на вопрос", var_2 = raw_input()
   надо присваивать переменную с новой строки после запятой:

   `print u"Ответьте на вопрос",
   var_2 = raw_input()`

p.s Спасибо @titov_andrei за направление поиска и @main за ответ в той теме.

Comment: не следует `''.join()` для строки вызывать.

Comment: @jfs почему не следует вызывать для строки?

Comment: какую операцию `result = ''.join(arg)` по вашему реализует, если arg строка?  Для наглядности, откройте REPL, поиграйтесь с разными arg значениями и сравните их с result.

Comment: @jfc Я понял. Спасибо.